# how can I push to master branch from jenkins using ssh key of other user

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I don´t know if this can be done, but I need to push changes to a bitbucket master branch repository in a jenkins job. Let´s call it repo1 
Master branch of that repository has configure branch permissions to push just for 2 users. User_a and user_b. 
This users connect to bitbucket with user name and password. 
Also appart from this  user_a and user jenkins has configured in jenkins settings credentials, their   SSH key to connect to bitbucket. 
So basically when Jenkins need to pull code from BB and build some application, uses this credentials ID.

But now, one of the new jobs requested, has to make that jenkins can push into this repo 1 master branch.
Of course that I first received the permission error because only user_a and user_b can push into master.

So I now tried to configure that jenkis use credential ID of user_a (which ha permission into master branch to push)

But when I run the job I´m getting gollowing message

```
 git commit -m test
[master c078d06] gulp file generated
 Committer: Jenkins <jenkins@xxxx@xxxxx.com>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ git push origin master
remote: Permission denied to update branch master.To git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/repo1.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/repo1.git'
```

I configured this step as follow with user_a credential ID.

```
stage ('Pulling code from Bitbucket') {


        git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: '2bbbbbbb-aaaaaaaa--xxxx-eeeeeeeeeee', #user_a credential ID
                url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/repo1.git'

            sh 'sed -i "s/running/walking/g" README.md' #just changing something in readme for test
            sh 'git add .'
            sh 'git commit -m "test"'
            sh 'git push '


        }
```

So how can I accomplish this? I´m telling jenkins to use user_a credentials ID but is not working.
Also I can´t add user jenkins in bitbucket in repo1 master branch as it doesn´t have any user there with user and password , jenkins just connects to bitbucket with ssh key. Same way as user_a (which also has user and pass). 
How can I push into master using user_a credential ID, that is the user that has permission in master branch? apparently the aproach I tried didn´t worked.
Thank you.-

Comment: If the user_a uses username and password then you should use git url with https or http right ? not git@bitbucket.....

Comment: that´s the thing, I don´t want to harcode user in jenkins output , is there another way?

Comment: You dont need to hardcode, you can still use credentialsId but you have to change url to have https or http

Comment: any idea of how to scape a special charcter "@" for example in password As I tried that way and I got : fatal: unable to access 'https://user_a:xxxx@456@bitbucket.org/user_a/repo1.git. I asume with credential Id will have same problem

Comment: got it : %40 for the @. thanks